# Qt connect doesn't works

Tags: c++, qt4, qt5, publish-subscribe

I've a C++ library. This library uses the publish-subscriber pattern.

```
namespace mylib {
typedef unsigned MyLibType;
class IEvent
{
    virutal ~IEvent() {}

    virtual void event1() = 0;
     virtual void event2(MyLibType) = 0;
};

class IMyClass
{
public:
    virtual ~IMyClass() {}

    // operations
};

} // mylib

// C interface
int CreateMyClass( mylib::IMyClass** class, mylib::IEvent* listener );

// implementation
class MyClass : public IMyClass { // ...
```

When MyClass is create uses a thread that generate some events.

Now on Qt:

```
class QtMyApplication : public QMainWindow, public mylib::IEvent
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QtMyApplication(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QtMyApplication();

signals:
    void MyLibEvent1();
    void MyLibEvent2(mylib::MyLibType);

private slots:
    void OnMyLibEvent1();
    void OnMyLibEvent2(mylib::MyLibType);

private: // IEvent interface
    void event1()
    {
        emit MyLibEvent1();
    }

    void event2(mylib::MyLibType i)
    {
        emit OnMyLibEvent2( i );
    }

private:
    Ui::QtMyApplication* ui;
    mylib::IMyLib mMyLib;
};

// implementation
QtMyApplication::QtMyApplication( QWidget *parent ) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::QtMyApplication)
{
    ui->setupUi( this );

    CreateMyLib( &mMyLib, this );

    connect( this, SIGNAL(MyLibEvent1()),
             this, SLOT(OnMyLibEvent1()) );
    connect( this, SIGNAL(MyLibEvent2(mylib::MyLibType)),
             this, SLOT(OnMyLibEvent2(mylib::MyLibType)) );
}
```

When I run the application event2() is called inside QtMyApplication but OnMyLibEvent2 is never called, instead event1() is called and OnMyLibEvent1 is called too.
What am I wrong? Is the argument parameter the issue?

**edit 1**

I discovered that the connect has some restriction on params.... because if I change `MyLibEvent2(mylib::MyLibType)` in `MyLibEvent2(int)` all works properly...

Comment: probably event2() is never called?

Comment: `event2` is executed and it calls `emit MyLibEvet2(i)` but `OnMyLibEvet2` is never called

Comment: another strange thing is that Qt prints: `pc 0x400 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.` on output window

Comment: one thing I stumbled over a few times was that `connect` does not check case or spelling. so make extra sure there is no upper-lower-case mismatch or a missing character. the compiler won't complain, but your function wouldn't be called

Comment: one parameter of the IEvent is a typedef. Can be that the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your datatype to QTs metatype system to make it work:

```
qRegisterMetaType<mylib::MyLibType>();
```

QTs metatype system does not know about typedefs, and therefore does not know how to transfer a mylib::MyLibType.
I'm not exactly shure if you need `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(mylib::MyLibType)` too, try it if you have no success.

If you use QT5s new connection syntax then it might also work without any additonal effort.

```
connect( this, &QtMyApplication::MyLibEvent2,
         this, &QtMyApplication::OnMyLibEvent2);
```

The problem is that the old connect syntax is working around the metadata system and string comparisons and is fairly fragile. It also won't work if you decide to update your slot to `void OnMyLibEvent2(::mylib::MyLibType)`